# How to make `cookie` available in certain path but not in its subdirectories

Tags: php, cookies

In `php`, I use `setcookie` to create a cookie, as the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) says, if you do not specify the `path` parameter, the cookie will be available in the current directory **and all of its sub-directories**. But I need the cookie will be available only in current directory and not in its sub-directories. How can I achieve this?

```
//it is available in current directory and all of its sub-directories:
setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
//with the same effect:
setcookie("TestCookie", $value,/current-directory/);
```

I want to exclude `/current-directory/*`

Thank you very much

Comment: I dont know a solution within the `setcookie()` function. You could simply checks the path of the current script/uri with `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` or `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` and a regex beforehand to use or ignore the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible.

But you could store your information the `$_SESSION` variable and do the path check by yourself using `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`.

> The path option
>
> Another way to control when the Cookie header will be sent is to specify the path option. Similar to the domain option, path indicates a URL path that must exist in the requested resource before sending the Cookie header. This comparison is done by comparing the option value character-by-character against the start of the request URL. If the characters match, then the Cookie header is sent. Sample:
>
> `Set-Cookie: name=Nicholas; path=/blog`
>
> In this example, the path option would match /blog, /blogroll, etc.; anything that begins with /blog is valid. Note that this comparison is only done once the domain option has been verified. The default value for the path option is the path of the URL that sent the Set-Cookie header.

source: https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/